# How to find indices of NA values in one matrix and remove these indices from another matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, na

I have 2 matrix (8760,318).

```
A = 1 2 3 4 
    5 6 7 8 
    9 0 1 11
    1 8 3 7

B = NA NA NA NA
    NA NA NA NA
    1  3  5  7
    2  4  6  8
```

I would like to find the indices of NA values in Matrix B and remove values corresponding to these indices in Matrix A and Matrix B. In the end I would like to have

```
A = 9 0 1 11
    1 8 3 7

B = 1 3 5 7
    2 4 6 8
```

I also would like to protect matrix form (x,318). All methods I have tried so far, broke the matrix form and gave me a vector with 1 row.

Comment: If the goal is to remove rows having all NAs, then `A[!rowSums(!is.na(B)),]`

Comment: this is working fine for Matrix A, but there is a problem that dimensions of matrix A and B are not same after I removed NA values from Matrix B also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For A (lil bit hacky, maybe i will edit)

```
A[!is.na(B)[,1],]
```

For B

```
na.omit(B)
```

Comment: `matrix(A[!is.na(B)],ncol=ncol(A))`

Answer (score 0):

What about putting to `NA` all the values in A that are `NA` in B and apply na.omit() to A?

```
for (i in 1:nrow(B)) { for (j in 1:ncol(B)) { if (is.na(B[i,j])) A[i,j] = NA } }
```

`na.omit(A)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest converting to a data frame first.

```
A <- as.data.frame(A)
# 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
 # $ V1: num  1 5 9 1
 # $ V2: num  2 6 0 8
 # $ V3: num  3 7 1 3
 # $ V4: num  4 8 11 7

B <- as.data.frame(B)
```

Use the following to filter out rows where all entries are `NA`. This also ensures that you do not end up with a number of elements that cannot be formatted into a table-like structure

```
isrowallna <- apply(B, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))
```

Filter the data frame appropriately

```
A <- A[!isrowallna,]
B <- B[!isrowallna,]
```

Revert to matrix

```
A <- as.matrix(A)
 # num [1:2, 1:4] 9 1 0 8 1 3 11 7
 # - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  # ..$ : chr [1:2] "3" "4"
  # ..$ : chr [1:4] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4"

B <- as.matrix(B)
```

Your data

```
A = matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 6, 7, 8, 
    9, 0, 1, 11,
    1, 8, 3, 7), nrow=4, byrow=TRUE)

B = matrix(c(NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA,
    1,  3,  5,  7,
    2,  4,  6,  8), nrow=4, byrow=TRUE)
```